# Spring Boot 2.1.2 using classpath in .yml mvc config

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle

Got into this weird issue which reason i can't identify. Was migrating from spring mvc to spring boot 2 and want to keep using the `.jsp` views. Want to store `.jsp` views in `resources/templates`. However, they're not being loaded if placed there, but works if placed in `/WEB-INF/pages/`.

Question is - why is this happening? i've seem a lot of similar configs and it seems like a normal practice to store them in classpath.

**sample error log:**

```
2019-01-17 12:02:39,381 WARN  [http-nio-8080-exec-1] resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler (ResourceHttpRequestHandler.java:642)  - Path represents URL or has "url:" prefix: [classpath:/templates/login.jsp]
2019-01-17 12:02:39,382 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-1] resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler (ResourceHttpRequestHandler.java:453)  - Resource not found
2019-01-17 12:02:39,383 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-1] servlet.FrameworkServlet (FrameworkServlet.java:1126)  - Exiting from "FORWARD" dispatch, status 404
2019-01-17 12:02:39,384 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-1] servlet.FrameworkServlet (FrameworkServlet.java:1130)  - Completed 404 NOT_FOUN
```

Minimal config:

Spring Boot `2.1.2`

**application.properties**(not working):

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix: classpath:/templates/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp

logging.level.org.springframework.web: DEBUG
```

**application.properties**(working):

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/pages/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp

logging.level.org.springframework.web: DEBUG
```

**gradle**:

```
plugins {
    id 'war'
    id "io.spring.dependency-management" version "1.0.6.RELEASE"
    id "org.springframework.boot" version "2.1.2.RELEASE"
}

repositories {
    maven {
        url = 'http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2'

    compile "javax.servlet:jstl:1.2"
    //providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    providedRuntime "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper"
}

configurations {
    all {
        exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
    }
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}
```

**Update:**

I suppose it have something to do with tomcat. For example 
`providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'`
- does not load `.jsp` even from `/WEB-INF/pages`, while 
`providedRuntime "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper"` does load, but only from `/WEB-INF/pages`

**Update 2:**
So, it is somehow connected with tomcat & `.jsp` extension.
Additional `.jsp` problem:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:static/css/");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:static/js/");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/fonts/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:static/fonts/");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/view/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:static/view/");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/img/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:static/img/");
}
```

all the resources are loading except `.jsp` files in `/view/`. If i rename `.jsp` views files to `.html` - they're loaded. (however there is a lot of `.jsp` logic which i don't want to re-write)

Answer (score 0):

Your following configuration is the issue

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix: classpath:/templates/
```

Update your view resource handler configuration as follows.

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/view/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:static/view/");
```

Update it to,

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/view/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/resources/templates/view/");
```

Make sure your put all your jsp files in `/resources/templates/view/` directoy instead of `/static/view`

It worked for `.html` because I think spring boot did fallback to .html resolver when relevant jstl failed to find the views.